# ?Should functionality of code associated with Pivotviewer custom actions be lightweight?

Tags: wcf, performance, silverlight-4.0, custom-action, pivotviewer

All:

Our project uses Silverlight 4 and Microsoft Pivot Viewer.

I'm using Silverlight 4, and I would like to keep using Silverlight 4 for now.

The PivotViewer display in our project will using Custom Actions.
I figured out a way to add custom action buttons on top of each item image in PivotViewer.

My intention is to have "Add to cart" and "Remove" custom action buttons on top of each item image in PivotViewer.

Obviously, "Add to cart" custom action button will ultimately trigger some kind of method of a Web Service or WCF service that will add the item image to a personal account Shopping Cart ( i.e. basically my application will be accessing the database  ).

Obviously, "Remove" custom action button will ultimately trigger some kind of method of a Web Service or WCF service that will remove the item image to a personal account Shopping Cart ( i.e. basically my application will be accessing the database  ).

However, I vaguely remember that someone posted a comment on a blog stating that the custom actions associated with Pivot Viewer displays should be very light weight.

I'm just worried whether invoking a web service method when the custom action of a PivotViewer is invoked will be heavy weight.

Is this something I should be concerned about?

Thanks,

Comment: @jonnyGold Ok Accepted answers that I could accept.  May I please have your help?

Comment: As Professor Knuth said: ["Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming"](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth). Just write what you need and see it is slow enough to warrant worrying about.